# R Alternatives to View()? It's too slow on nested character vectors

Tags: r, tibble

`View()` is slow when there are nested character vectors; `View()` shows and crunches their appearance. A solution is to instead place these vectors inside data.frames or tibbles. But is there another fix or an alternative to View()?

```r
library(tidyverse)
## A small taste
st <- tibble(x = letters[1:10])
st <- st %>% mutate(
  nested_sentences = map(x, ~ sentences[1:3])
)

## Glut
glut <- tibble(x = letters[1:10])
glut <- glut %>% mutate(
  nested_sentences = map(x, ~ sentences)
)

## Solution
sol <- tibble(x = letters[1:10])
sol <- sol %>% mutate(
  nested_sentences = map(x, ~ tibble(sentences = sentences))
)

# View(st)
# View(glut)
# View(sol)

## It would be great if View(glut) showed similarly to tibble output
glut
#> # A tibble: 10 × 2
#>    x     nested_sentences
#>    <chr> <list>          
#>  1 a     <chr [720]>     
#>  2 b     <chr [720]>     
#>  3 c     <chr [720]>     
#>  4 d     <chr [720]>     
#>  5 e     <chr [720]>     
#>  6 f     <chr [720]>     
#>  7 g     <chr [720]>     
#>  8 h     <chr [720]>     
#>  9 i     <chr [720]>     
#> 10 j     <chr [720]>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: `object 'sentences' not found`

Comment: Have you tried using `str(...)` instead?

Comment: @r2evans Hmm reprex() seems to have failed me then. Will `library(stingr)` work?

Comment: Ahh, no, that's likely my fault ... I don't load `tidyverse`, way too much crud for my taste. I thought it was something else. Sorry about the false-alarm. (For what it's worth, I much prefer explicit individual packages used for a question, such as (in this case) `dplyr`, `purrr`, and `stringr`. Not everybody agrees with me. I usually do well-enough, I missed it this time.)

Comment: Just curious, what's the crud in `tidyverse()` you don't like?

Comment: Collisions, masking, order of packages I want, too many packages I don't use, generally namespace pollution. Since I only use (at most) 3-4 of the packages directly and don't need the dependent packages in my search-path.